# Download Copying to disc issue

Tags: system-installation, downloads

I am trying to download Ubuntu to run along side Windows.

After I download it - one version runs 774 mb and the other 900+ mb - I am required to burn to a disc but my discs only go to 700mb.

I tried downloading it to a flash drive but the program won't let me.

Any ideas/help/suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to burn to DVD not CD, these images don't fit on CD anymore.  I tried marking question as duplicate but chose wrong question to mark duplicate of and I can't re-do.

Answer (score 0):

That has been the case for a couple of releases. A CD is not going to work anymore. On the download page it states (it does not show that on the current Ubuntu download website itself though; I used the 15.04 version; that notice used to be on the 14.10 and 14.04 one too):

> Warning: This image is oversized (which is a bug) and will not fit onto a standard 703MiB CD. However, you may still test it using a DVD, a USB drive, or a virtual machine.

Alternatives ...

- Use a DVD.
- Use an USB flash drive.
- Use a partition on your hard disk and tell grub to start from it.

In case you MUST use a CD you could pick up a [server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) (578Mb) version and install the desktop from command line.

---

[Ubuntu 15.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) currently is 1.1 Gb and I doubt it is going to get smaller.

---

Regarding

> I tried downloading it to a flash drive but the program won't let me.

That wont work; you need to install it onto the flash drive and then you can boot from it and install it to disk. See [create usb stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

if you are already running on windows system, you can use Utilities to make the Ubuntu Bootable USB. My favourite is "Novicop". This program runs on windows and can easily make your usb bootable. I am sure that you can find other utilities with google search.

Only limitation for novicop is, you have to have the iso file mounted ( you can not direct path to the iso file), therefore you can use the daemons-tools light (this is a free available version) and mounts the ISO files on  windows by creating a virtual cd rom in the system. Therefore no more need to burn CD's or DVD's.

Good luck